# Access Raspberry pi jenkins server over the internet

Tags: networking, vpn

I have managed to setup up a working Jenkins server on my raspberry pi 2. The Pi has an IP address through a LAN cable connected into the wall. I cannot however access the Jenkins server from my laptop on a different network. I have changed the Jenkins server to use it's IP address and not the local one. Is there anyway I can access my Jenkins server on the raspberry pi on my computer on a different network?

Comment: What is a wall? A firewall? Are you sitting on a private network with a NATed router to the internet (the usual home configuration)? Where is the different network? Inside or outside of the firewall? Maybe you have to poke a hole into the firewall with port forwarding? Btw.: this is not really a specific question for raspberry pi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote communication with home server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9761/remote-communication-with-home-server)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're connecting your Raspi to your local networks and trying to access it from the internet which you cannot achieve via local networks connection.
I would suggest two thing 
1:
Get a public Ip from your ISP

2:
If you just want to access it for Remote Desktop you can do that by installing VNC and signup for RealVNC account and login to Raspi vnc server ->add device ->go to viewer device login with real vnc and you can see the devices in there and you can access it